# Is it possible to use CSS Custom Properties in values for the content property?

Tags: css, css-content, css-variables

Example:

```
:root {
    --PrimaryThemeColor: #3acfb6; /* with or without quotes */
}

.ColorSwatch:after {
  content: var(--PrimaryThemeColor);
}
```

When this is rendered, the computed CSS is literally that value.

```
content: var(--PrimaryThemeColor);
```

Even if I'm using a post-processor that injects the computed value as a fallback, the value itself isn't a string, so it's invalid for `content`.

```
.ColorSwatch:after {
    content: #3acfb6;
    content: var(--PrimaryThemeColor);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "with or without quotes"? It should work correctly with quotes.

Comment: Yes it's possible. But your issue seems to be converting a color to a string instead of using a variable in `content`.

Comment: The CSS variable works when applied to a CSS property, but not when applied to the content. CSS variables do not behave like javascript variables printing its value as string.

Comment: If the variable holds a number, [this is possible using CSS Counters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40179718/5545315).

Answer (score 7):

The value of the custom property has to be a string (either a string literal, an `attr()` expression, or in the case of `content` any combination of any number of said tokens) in order for the corresponding `var()` expression to work correctly anywhere that a string is expected.

It is not possible to convert a non-string value to a string or between any two data types through the `var()` function, if that's what you're asking. The value is always parsed, stored and substituted as-is, and the value can comprise any number of any kind of token, so converting between data types would be... pretty difficult.

Comment: Right, I pointed that out already. 
>  "the value itself isn't a string, so it's invalid for content."

Comment: @Kevin Suttle: Yeah - so you've answered your own question.

Comment: Seems like a reasonably common use case, so it would nice to extend the `var` syntax to be `var(--name type-or-unit)`. This would allow both `font-size: var(--size px)`, and thereby avoid the cumbersome `font-size: calc(1px * var(--size))`, and in the case here, would allow `content: var(--primaryThemeColor string)`. (`type-of-unit` here, of course, has the same semantics as when used in the `attr()` function.)